# Mathieu function rescale problem

Tags: special-functions

The Mathieu functions are the solutions for the equation

$$
y''+(a-2q\cos(2z))y=0
$$

If we require the solution has the form

$$
y(z) = e^{i r z}f(z)
$$

where $f(z)$ is a periodic function with period of $2\pi$, then the parameter $a$ should satisfy Mathieu characteristic function

$$
a=\text{MatheiuCharacteristicA}(r,q)
$$

My question is what's the condition of $a$ should satisfy, if the solution can be written as

$$
y(z)=e^{irz}f(z)
$$

where $f(z)$ is a periodic function with period 1, i.e., $f(z+1)=f(z)$?

*Update*

It seems that the period of the original Mathieu function should be $\pi$ instead of $2\pi$, according to  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory#Floquet.27s_theorem_applied_to_Mathieu_equation), [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloquetsTheorem.html), and [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#iii), and the documentation of Mathematica may be [incorrect on that](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58745/1364). That means the ordinary scaling  of the equation works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Scilab Mathieu Functions Toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/Mathieu/), not Mathematica.

The parameter *a* (or *b*) is a function of order *r* and value of *q* - $a_r(q)$ (or $b_r(q)$), the dependency may be illustrated as follows
[image: a_r(q), b_r(q)] (from aforementioned [toolbox](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/mathieu/page/Demos-2/)).

You can read the following documents about Mathieu functions:

- N.W. McLachlan, Theory and Application of Mathieu Functions, Oxford Univ. Press, 1947.
- [Chapter 28 Mathieu Functions and Hill's Equation. Digital Library of
  Mathematical Functions. NIST](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28).
- help and documents of [Scilab Mathieu Functions Toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/Mathieu/)

If you are interested - the toolbox installation procedure is as follows:

1. Install [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org/)
2. Start Scilab
3. Update ATOMS database with `atomsSystemUpdate`
4. Install Mathieu Functions Toolbox with `atomsInstall('Mathieu')`
5. Restart Scilab, launch its help (? -> Scilab Help), navigate to 'Mathieu functions' or launch demo (? -> Scilab Demonstrations -> Mathieu functions).